# Greedy algorithm for debt payment when choosing which debt to pay off first.

Tags: algorithms, finance

I wish to find a greedy algorithm for solving the following problem:

Given a set of debts, having an original value $X_{i}$ and an interest rate $r_{i}$ (meaning, they behave like a geometric series $X_{i} \cdot r_{i}^{q}$ for $q$ number of months), that can differ from each other, and a monthly amount to use for paying them $Tot$: I want to minimize the number of months needed for finishing paying all of them.

In other words, for each months I need to decide which debts I want to pay. Those not chosen, will be multiplied by $r_{i}$. And in the next month I'll have $Tot$ restarted, and I'll choose which of the remaining debts I'd want to cover. Repeating this until I reach a month having all my debts paid.

My first idea was to sort the debts somehow and then in a greedy manner choose as much as I can until I reach $Tot$. My problem was understating how should I sort them, neither the original debt amount nor the interest rate seemed to do the trick.

Comment: If i understand the problem correctly and debt keep incurring interest until they are repaid, then it seem intuitive that the problem is equivalent to minimizing the total amount repaid.

Comment: If you pay $T$ cash on a debt of interest rate $r$, it is equivalent to paying $r*T$ next month. So for a given month, here is one heuristic algorithm: select the the debt with the largest interest rate that you are able to pay-off with your current cash, then pay it. Repeat this procedure until your remaining cash that month is insufficient to pay any other debt.

Comment: @user3257842 I understand your suggestion, but I have difficulties proving it gives an optimal solution: Say the algorithm chose to pay debt $i$ on the first month, and the optimal solution pays it on month $y$. Then we can say for sure that the optimal solution chose a debt with a lower interest rate for the first month, and I'd want to replace the the payment plans of months $1$, $y$. When we can see easily why we can pay for $y$ also on the first month, I believe it's possible to think of counter example for a month $1$ (that as a result of the interest) we won't be able to pay on $y$.

Comment: Can you pay for example half of a given debt in a month if you have insufficient cash to pay it all? Or is it always all or nothing? If you are able to pay debts partially then you can always spend your entire $Tot$ every given moth and it's (relatively) easy to prove that going for the highest interest rates first gives you the best results. If, on the other hand, individual debt-payment is all or nothing, then your problem is related to the Knapsack problem, and a truly optimal algorithm might be NP-hard (tough I'm not certain). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @user3257842 It's all or nothing I'm afraid... If I would like make use of a solution for the Knapsack, there's a better way than run it through all the remaining debts for each month? Meaning, a way to run an algorithm through the whole input and in one scan to obtain a what debt payments to deal with each month.